# SQL AVG function to not consider empty cells

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table where some cells are empty. I want to get the average of all columns, but for some reason the empty cells are counted too.

**One column has 5 empty cells and 5 times the value of 100. So the average should be 100, but I get 50.** I tried COALESCE, NVL and "WHERE column IS NOT NULL" but that didn't give me the result I want. Other cells have 0 as a value and those have to be counted.

This is my query (it's based on a checkbox selection)

```
foreach($_POST['aufg'] AS $value) {
            $sql .= "AVG({$value}1) as {$value}1, AVG({$value}2) as {$value}2, ";
        }

        $sql  = substr($sql, 0, -2);
        $sql .= " FROM table";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are simply wrong under most normal circumstances.  If the values are *really* `NULL`, then they are ignored.  So, if the table has 10 rows with this data:

```
value
100
100
100
100
100
null
null
null
null
null
```

The average is 100.  That is how MySQL works.  That is how SQL works.  `NULL` values are ignored in aggregation functions.

The one circumstance where what you say is true is in the following situation:

- The column is a string.
- The value is `'null'` (the string) rather than `NULL` the value.

In this case, the `'null'` values are implicitly converted to numbers for the numeric calculation.  The value given is zero.

I discount this possibility because numbers should be stored as numbers not strings.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=715b12c3511ac6c71d8fdfbe499015dd) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Yeah that's why I am confused. The cells are actually empty though. The data type is varchar, is that the problem? Would changing it to decimal solve it?

Comment: Empty varchar values (i.e. empty strings like `''`) are probably getting interpreted as 0 as @GordonLinoff mentioned in his answer. Try setting those empty strings to NULL and it should work as you want

Comment: Thank you, I just checked and I did put in empty strings. Changed them to NULL and now it works. Just one thing now, how can they be NULL by default? I use variables from a form to make the sql statement that inserts the data. Parts of the form might be hidden to some users, so in that case I set those to empty strings. I tried $var = NULL; instead but that didn't work.

Comment: @JD26 . . . The values *are* `NULL` by default unless you declare them to have another `DEFAULT` value.

Comment: I know. My problem is this piece of code
`if (isset ($_POST['VP1'])) {
                                $VP1 = $_POST['VP1'];
                            } else {
                                $VP1 = "";
                            };
`
$VP1 is later used in the sql query that inserts the data. Replacing "" with NULL didn't work, and deleting this whole piece of code didn't either.